# php insert to mysql multiple inputs over 100

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, insert-into

I've created a user form in which once the submit button is pressed I would like to send/insert the data to mysql database adding a new record. The form has over 100 input fields. How can I accomplish this. Here is my sample php code.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){


//Variables for connecting to your database.
            //These variable values come from your hosting account.
            $hostname = "hostname";
            $username = "username";
            $password = "password";
            $dbname = "dbname";
            $mystuff = "tenant_lname","tenant_fname","tenant_mname","ssn","dl_number","dl_state","birthday","tenant_hphone","tenant_wphone","tenant_cphone","curr_street","curr__unit","curr_city","curr_state","curr_zip","how_long_from","how_long_to","last_rent_mnt","last_rent_amt","own_man_name","own_man_tel","curr_reason","pre_street","pre_unit","pre_city","pre_state","pre_zip","pre_from","pre_to","pre_last_rent","pre_amt","pre_owner","pre_owner_tel","pre_reason","sec_pre_street","sec_pre_unit","sec_pre_city","sec_pre_state","sec_pre_zip","sec_pre_from","sec_pre_to","sec_pre_last_paid_mnt","sec_pre_amt","sec_pre_owner","sec_pre_owner_tel","sec_pre_reason","curr_emp_name","curr_emp_add","curr_emp_phone","curr_emp_pos","curr_emp_bus_type","curr_emp_sup","curr_emp_from","curr_emp_to","curr_emp_salary","pre_emp_name","pre_emp_add","pre_emp_phone","pre_emp_pos","pre_emp_bus_type","pre_emp_sup_name","pre_emp_from","pre_emp_to","pre_emp_salary","move_date","addntl_occ_name","addntl_occ_age","addntl_occ_relation","addntl_ft","addntl_pt","addntl_occ1_name","addntl_occ1_age","addntl_occ1_relation","addntl_occ1_ft","addntl_occ1_pt","addntl_occ2_name","addntl_occ2_age","addnt2_occ1_relation","addntl_occ2_ft","addntl_occ2_pt","addntl_occ3_name","addntl_occ3_age","addntl_occ3_relation","addntl_occ3_ft","addntl_occ3_pt","credit_yes","credit_no","det_yes","det_no","evict_yes","evict_no","bnkry_yes","bnkry_no","fel_yes","fel_no","pet_yes","pet_no","pet_numb","pet_type","furn_yes","furn_no","ins_cov_yes","ins_cov_no","ints_yes","ints_no","ints_type","smoke_yes","smoke_no","occ_smoke_yes","occ_smoke_no","explain_smoke","bnk_name","bnk_add","checking","checking_bal","saving","saving_bal","bnk_name1","bnk_add1","checking1","checking_bal1","saving1","saving_bal1","other_income","credit_name","credit_add","credit_city","credit_acct","credit_bal","credit_payment","credit_name1","credit_add1","credit_city1","credit_acct1","credit_bal1","credit_payment1","credit_acct2_name","credit_add2","credit_city2","credit_acc2","credit_bal2","credit_payment2","credit_acc3_name","credit_acc3_add","credit_acc3_city","credit_acc3_number","credit_acc3_bal","credit_acc3_payment","emer_contact_name","emer_contact_add","emer_relation","emer_phone","reg_owner_yes","reg_owner_no","reg_who","vehicle_year","vehicle_make","vehicle_model","vehicle_color","vehicle_license","veh_state","vehicle2_year","vehicle2_make","vehicle2_model","vehicle2_color","vehicle2_license","veh2_state";



$con = mysql_connect("$hostname","$username","$password");
if (!$con){
die ("Can not connect:" . mysql_error());   
}

mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);

$sql = "INSERT INTO dbname ($mystuff) VALUES ('$_POST[$mystuff]')";

mysql_query($sql,$con);

mysql_close($con);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) SQL Injection. Please read up on it. http://cwe.mitre.org/top25/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection
2) Stop using `mysql_query()` - it's deprecated and leads to unsafe code.
3) Get each field and put it in the insert query according to the column in the database...

Comment: and now change your password

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest simply write this manually. Don't be so lazy. And use PDO instead of `mysql_query` because it is future safe. Read the documentation on http://php.net.

Comment: @Philip, I don't have a clue what you're talking about. I'm just a beginner at this and your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a clue what you're talking about. I'm just a beginner at this and your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change $mystuff to an array and use foreach to loop through the array and generate post data.

```
$mystuff = array("tenant_lname","tenant_fname","tenant_mname","ssn","dl_number","dl_state","birthday","tenant_hphone","tenant_wphone","tenant_cphone","curr_street","curr__unit","curr_city","curr_state","curr_zip","how_long_from","how_long_to","last_rent_mnt","last_rent_amt","own_man_name","own_man_tel","curr_reason","pre_street","pre_unit","pre_city","pre_state","pre_zip","pre_from","pre_to","pre_last_rent","pre_amt","pre_owner","pre_owner_tel","pre_reason","sec_pre_street","sec_pre_unit","sec_pre_city","sec_pre_state","sec_pre_zip","sec_pre_from","sec_pre_to","sec_pre_last_paid_mnt","sec_pre_amt","sec_pre_owner","sec_pre_owner_tel","sec_pre_reason","curr_emp_name","curr_emp_add","curr_emp_phone","curr_emp_pos","curr_emp_bus_type","curr_emp_sup","curr_emp_from","curr_emp_to","curr_emp_salary","pre_emp_name","pre_emp_add","pre_emp_phone","pre_emp_pos","pre_emp_bus_type","pre_emp_sup_name","pre_emp_from","pre_emp_to","pre_emp_salary","move_date","addntl_occ_name","addntl_occ_age","addntl_occ_relation","addntl_ft","addntl_pt","addntl_occ1_name","addntl_occ1_age","addntl_occ1_relation","addntl_occ1_ft","addntl_occ1_pt","addntl_occ2_name","addntl_occ2_age","addnt2_occ1_relation","addntl_occ2_ft","addntl_occ2_pt","addntl_occ3_name","addntl_occ3_age","addntl_occ3_relation","addntl_occ3_ft","addntl_occ3_pt","credit_yes","credit_no","det_yes","det_no","evict_yes","evict_no","bnkry_yes","bnkry_no","fel_yes","fel_no","pet_yes","pet_no","pet_numb","pet_type","furn_yes","furn_no","ins_cov_yes","ins_cov_no","ints_yes","ints_no","ints_type","smoke_yes","smoke_no","occ_smoke_yes","occ_smoke_no","explain_smoke","bnk_name","bnk_add","checking","checking_bal","saving","saving_bal","bnk_name1","bnk_add1","checking1","checking_bal1","saving1","saving_bal1","other_income","credit_name","credit_add","credit_city","credit_acct","credit_bal","credit_payment","credit_name1","credit_add1","credit_city1","credit_acct1","credit_bal1","credit_payment1","credit_acct2_name","credit_add2","credit_city2","credit_acc2","credit_bal2","credit_payment2","credit_acc3_name","credit_acc3_add","credit_acc3_city","credit_acc3_number","credit_acc3_bal","credit_acc3_payment","emer_contact_name","emer_contact_add","emer_relation","emer_phone","reg_owner_yes","reg_owner_no","reg_who","vehicle_year","vehicle_make","vehicle_model","vehicle_color","vehicle_license","veh_state","vehicle2_year","vehicle2_make","vehicle2_model","vehicle2_color","vehicle2_license","veh2_state");

$post_data = '';
$post_array = implode(',',$mystuff);
foreach($mystuff as $value)
{
    $post_data .=($post_data)? ",'".$_POST[$value]."'" : "'".$_POST[$value]."'" ;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO dbname ($post_array) VALUES ($post_data)";
```